# C Functions not being exported

Tags: c, visual-c++, dll, dllimport, dllexport

After I had finished an assigment, in which one had to implement a Win32 window, I wanted to export my functions to a dll.

Surprisingly the linker complains about unreferenced links, altough

- __declspec(dllexport) / __declspec(dllimport) is defined and used correctly (or as I am used to from C++).
- the library is correctly specified to the linker.
- the functions are visible within dependency walker.

The linker always complains (in german):

> error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgel÷stes externes Symbol
>   ""__declspec(dllimport) struct cw_Window * __cdecl createWindow(char
>   *,unsigned short,unsigned short)" (__imp_?createWindow@@YAPEAUcw_Window@@PEADGG@Z)" in Funktion "main".
>   C:\Users\jkirs\Desktop\Workspace\MSVC2015_x86_64-release\Unit.MSVC2015-x86-64.88a6cdd3\intermediate.Unit.exe
>   : fatal error LNK1120: 1 nicht aufgel÷ste Externe

My functions prototypes are defined as following:

```
typedef struct cw_Window    cw_Window_t;
typedef struct cw_Event     cw_Event_t;

API cw_Window_t*    createWindow(char* pTitle, uint16_t nWidth, uint16_t nHeight);
API void            destroyWindow(cw_Window_t* pWindow);
API void            pollEvent(cw_Window_t* pWindow, cw_Event_t* pEvent);
```

where as "API" is defined as following:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #ifdef CW_EXPORT
        #define API __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
#else
    #define API // TODO
#endif
```

I tried to add 'extern "C" to the 'API' definition as well, without a result, but complaining about the string literal 'C'.

Has anyone come across this issue himself yet and can point me towards the right direction?

If it matters: I am uinsg Visual Studio C++ 2015 (MSVC_x86_64); my header files end with '.h' and source files end with '.c'.

EDIT:
The lib is supposed to be used in C code again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, everything I made was just fine but the build system.
Turns out the buildsystem treaded the file as an C++ Source File instead of plain C.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems you knew the basic problem and approximate solution with `extern "C"`. But your mistake is: don't put `extern "C"` in the API define. Wrap the definitions and declarations with it:

```
typedef struct cw_Window    cw_Window_t;
typedef struct cw_Event     cw_Event_t;

extern "C" {
API cw_Window_t*    createWindow(char* pTitle, uint16_t nWidth, uint16_t nHeight);
API void            destroyWindow(cw_Window_t* pWindow);
API void            pollEvent(cw_Window_t* pWindow, cw_Event_t* pEvent);
}
```

I know it looks like `extern` and what you were trying seems like a sensible place to put extern, but `extern "C"` is a different beast with different rules; you can read more than you want to about it here [In C++ source, what is the effect of extern "C"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c)